# psycopg2 column is of type date[] but expression is of type text[]

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I am trying to save an array of dates. I am providing a list of date objects, yet psycopg2 is throwing the above error.

Any thoughts on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PostgreSQL error: you need an explicit cast. Add `::date[]` after the value or the placeholder.