# psycopg2 execute_values - Update Query with Multiple Place holder - Throwing error - column is of type date but expression is of type text

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to replicate the answer provided by @jjanes to handle one of the `UPDATE` scenario.

[Psycopg2 execute values -the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470868/psycopg2-execute-values-the-query-contains-more-than-one-s-placeholder)

My code is as follows:

```
UPDATE_QUERY = """UPDATE SHARE_RETURN_DOC
                                      SET TO_DB_TS = v1,
                                          SUPERSEDED_DT = v2,
                                          FIRST_SEEN_DT = v3,
                                          LAST_SEEN_DT = v4,
                                          BATCH_ID = v5,
                                          DATA_PROC_ID = v6,
                                          CO_REG_DEBT = v7,
                                          DIR_DTL_CHG_IN = v8,
                                          SHRHLDR_LIST_CD = v9,
                                          SHRHLDR_LIST_CD = v10,
                                          SHRHLDR_LEGAL_STAT = v11,
                                          SHRHLDR_REFRESH_CD = v12,
                                          SHRHLDR_SUPRESS_IN = v13,
                                          BULK_LIST_ID = v14,
                                          DOC_TYPE_CD = v15,
                                          JACKET_NR = v16
                                     FROM (VALUES %s) u(id1, id2, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, 
                                                        v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16)                                                    
                                    WHERE SHARE_RETURN_DOC.REG_NB = u.id1
                                      AND SHARE_RETURN_DOC.ANN_RTN_DT = u.id2"""
```

`Method` to Execute the `Update SQL`:

```
def tableUpdate(connection, cursor, query, dataframe):
    data = []
    dataframe = dataframe.toPandas()
    for x in dataframe.to_numpy():
        data.append(tuple(x))
    try:
        print(data)
        extras.execute_values(cursor, query, data)
        connection.commit()
    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        connection.rollback()
        return 1
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

The `data` I am trying to pass to `extras.execute_value` is a `list` of 3 `tuples` combined. So I have 3 rows to `Update` in the table. The `data` is as below:

```
[('XXXXXXXX', datetime.date(2022, 12, 1), Timestamp('2023-03-16 09:51:31.634000'), **None**, datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), '5e3642ee-3f91-4360-8694-d60e66317af2', 1, 0, 'N', '2', None, ' ', ' ', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'XXXWUC94'), ('ZZZZZZZZ', datetime.date(2022, 11, 1), Timestamp('2023-03-16 09:51:31.634000'), None, datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), '5e3642ee-3f91-4360-8694-d60e66317af2', 1, 0, 'N', '2', None, ' ', ' ', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'ZZZWUC95'), ('YYYYYYYY', datetime.date(2022, 11, 21), Timestamp('2023-03-16 09:51:31.634000'), None, datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), datetime.date(2023, 3, 16), '5e3642ee-3f91-4360-8694-d60e66317af2', 1, 0, 'N', '7', None, ' ', ' ', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'YYYYY9D')]
```

However, I am getting an `Error`, while running the job:

The `method` is expecting `Date` Field. but the input data row contains `**None**`.

```
column "superseded_dt" is of type date but expression is of type text
LINE 3: ...                                         SUPERSEDED_DT = v2,
                                                                    ^
```

I tried the following options, which led to different other errors.
`SUPERSEDED_DT = v2::date[],`
`FROM (VALUES %s) u(id1, id2, v1, v2::date[], v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8,`

Could you please help me in fixing the issue.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: The actual data contains `None`. I have added **, just to highlight.

Comment: Why are you casting to a date array, if it supposed to just be a date scalar?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to implement the solution provided in the link. may be I am wrong.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854532/psycopg2-column-is-of-type-date-but-expression-is-of-type-text

Comment: Now, tried this
SUPERSEDED_DT = v2::date,. The error is gone now.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes for asking the right question. Still I have a doubt. Under what circumstances, we have to declare the datatypes explicitly. Is it only incases of Null?

Answer (score 1):

when you're setting the columns to update, typecast the temporary table column to the type of original table column, because in temporary table each column is of type text.

for example:

```
UPDATE_QUERY = """UPDATE SHARE_RETURN_DOC
                              SET TO_DB_TS = v1,
                                  SUPERSEDED_DT = v2::timestamp without time zone,
                                  FIRST_SEEN_DT = v3,
                                  LAST_SEEN_DT = v4,
                                  BATCH_ID = v5,
                                  DATA_PROC_ID = v6,
                                  CO_REG_DEBT = v7,
                                  DIR_DTL_CHG_IN = v8,
                                  SHRHLDR_LIST_CD = v9,
                                  SHRHLDR_LIST_CD = v10,
                                  SHRHLDR_LEGAL_STAT = v11,
                                  SHRHLDR_REFRESH_CD = v12,
                                  SHRHLDR_SUPRESS_IN = v13,
                                  BULK_LIST_ID = v14,
                                  DOC_TYPE_CD = v15,
                                  JACKET_NR = v16
                             FROM (VALUES %s) u(id1, id2, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, 
                                                v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16)                                                    
                            WHERE SHARE_RETURN_DOC.REG_NB = u.id1
                              AND SHARE_RETURN_DOC.ANN_RTN_DT = u.id2"""
```